# JavaScript Random Numbering With Decimals

Tags: javascript, random, decimal

my very first question on this very useful site:

I have made a function to create random generated numbers in JavaScrpt even with decimals.  Inputs has to be integers at this moment, I have planned to change that, but not for now.

**Function :**

```
function randomNumber(lowest, highest, power) {
    lowest = Math.floor(lowest);
    highest = Math.floor(highest);
    var factor = Math.pow(10, (power || 0));
    var result = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (factor * (highest - lowest) + 1)) + (factor * lowest)) / factor;
    return result;
}
```

**Question :**

is there a better way to achieve the desired result ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `power` parameter in your function?

Comment: @JLRishe to get numbers a factor higher than expected which than can be "floored" after which they get devided by factor. When not given automatically value 0 is chosen otherwise it gets the value given in the function call

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't really make it any clearer to me. So, suppose someone called `randomNumber(0, 30, 3)`, what would be the expected set of possible values?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var num=(Math.random()*49+1).toFixed(3);

   alert(num);

</script>
```

This will generate a random number with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I get what you are trying to do, but see if this along the lines of what you need.

```
function genRandNumber(num, max) {
    var max = max || 10000;
    return Math.floor((Math.floor(num * Math.random(max)) + Math.random()) * 10) / 10;
}

genRandNumber(2000)
```